# split a bigger list into smaller chunks when certain pattern occur in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list containing element like: listOfsentences=['Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail']

Now I want to split this list into smaller lists containing ['Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail'] and ['Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail'] That is splitting the list when 2 consecutive string is 'Fail'.

I have tried this code,but it doesn't seems to work

```
chunk1 =[]
for index in range(len(listOfsentences)):
    if a[index]=='Pass':
        current_index = index
        for ind,value in enumerate(listOfsentences):
            print(value)
            chunk1.append(a[ind])
            if listOfsentences[ind+1] == 'Fail' and listOfsentences[ind+2]== 'Fail':
                break
```

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

listOfsentences=['Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail']
result = [[]]
for k, v in groupby(listOfsentences):
    v = list(v)
    result[-1].extend(v)
    if k == "Fail" and len(v) > 1:
        result.append([])

result = list(filter(None, result))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail'],
 ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail']]
```

Comment: Will this work if a list contains pattern like['Pass','Pass','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail']

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rakesh. Your solution was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code, hope this will help:

```
data = ['Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Pass','Fail','Fail']


index = [i+1 for i in range(len(data)) if data[i]=="Fail" and data[i-1] == "Fail" and i != len(data)-1]
new_data = [data[0:index[0]],data[index[0]:index[1]],data[index[1]:]]
print(new_data)
```

Output will be :

```
[['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail'], ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail'], ['Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Pass', 'Fail', 'Fail']]
```